# How to load angular controller and template in a single HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs. want to load parts of a page that I package as "components", wherein a component contains its controller, template, directives and a few other assets like CSS etc. When needed, I want to load all of this on demand.

I was able to load the controller and the template on-demand by specifying a resolver for the controller and the templateUrl for the template. But is there any way I can combine them into a single HTTP request? Any examples?

Sorry forgot to add: I want to do it only on-demand, not precompiled/pre-aggregated (lets just say thats is a requirement thats been given to me). Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use angular templatecache to add your html to a module and package template cache along with controller, services, directives etc.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pull your Angular code and your html templates together in one request from the server, you'd need to have the templates combined in with your js. That would imply using some kind of job to process your html into js and concatenate it in with the rest of your code. Something like [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates) might do the trick.

### Edit

With the added requirement that this should be an on-demand sort of thing, I could only add (with the current information) that this sort of thing **can** be accomplished with bundling and request processing on the server, but the specifics on how to do this are totally dependent on your specific server stack. Often a server will have features that allow for on-demand resource bundling, or rendering of partial-views that might be helpful in this capacity.

Comment: Thanks, just edited my question to add. I want to do it without precompiling/aggregating and loading upfront (truly on-demand, but with just one HTTP request). I should have mentioned this first time.